# Is there a way to see users from a specific country?

Tags: support

I'd like to see who else from Bolivia is here. Maybe I find a work colleague. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way is the **[StackExchange data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com)**.

I just made a quick user search query for you: http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/1051/users-from

Type in "Bolivia" and there you go! There were **4** at the last import on February 10. Imports are done once a month.